# Throat hurting when singing

Tags: voice-training

I started singing when I was little but I never did vocal warm ups. Now that I'm more mature I started doing vocal warm ups but it hurts my throat. I thought it was nothing so I just went to singing and now every time I sing my throat hurts. I've tried many different vocal warm ups and they aren't working. I've tried apps and I've looked through some YouTube videos to see what the problem might be but those didn't work either. Singing and Music are the only things that can make me genuinely calm when I'm having a hard time and I don't want to stop doing it so what can I do and what's my problem?

Comment: Stop singing and go to a specialist, otherwise you risk never being able to sing any more.

Comment: Are you taking lessons?  Based on what you have written it sounds like you have not trained to do the warm ups correctly.  You could hurt your throat if you keep this up.

Comment: @ggcg  no I don't take lessons but i'm soon signing up for some.

Comment: @PiedPiper ok ill stop singing..i still want to sing so i'll listen to you advice :) thanks

Comment: With a teacher's help you will be fine.